# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER on a test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved
>   because it failed to trigger a flow. 
> A flow trigger failed to
>   execute the flow with version ID 301a00000004WPm. 
>  Contact your
>   administrator for help.: [] Stack Trace:
>   Class.UCaseTests.testMethod1_UCase: line 53, column 1

Comment: Has any one got an answer to this question? If so please help me to get through the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Check if below link might has more information about your problem. https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Xn7AAE

Answer (score 0):

You would have received an email from salesforce stating the details of the error or find out that error by putting debug logs.I got this error in the past when i was submitting a record for approval through process builder.In my case the name of the approval process was invalid.Check your scenario and find the error details.